# How to add a simple SVG using D3 and ES2015

Tags: d3.js, ecmascript-6

I have a ES2015 project using Webpack. I am trying to add D3v4 so I add the following...

```
// Typescript
import { select } from 'd3';
...
select(".application").append("svg"); // line 22
```

I have also tried...

```
import { select } from 'd3-selection';
```

But this throws an exception...

> ERROR in ./src/main/angular/app/app.component.ts
>   (22,12): error TS1138: Parameter declaration expected.

What is the correct way to do this? Is there any D3 documentation for ES2015?

Comment: That should work - there is something else going with your setup.

Comment: Any more info I can give you that will help? Simple webpack pipeline. I will try to make a simple project this week.

Comment: Can you put together a quick gist with the project files? That way I can try to reproduce the error.

Comment: Will do for now you can just try to add d3 to this https://github.com/jrgleason/ng2-webpack-demo that is the basis of it

Comment: Sorry it took so long here is the d3 branch... https://github.com/jrgleason/ng2-webpack-spring-boot-scala-example/tree/d3